# Windows mobile Windows Messages tracing utility

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-mobile

I'm looking for small utility to run on windows mobile phone and trace all windows messages it receive. Not message codes, but names if it could figure them out.

I could probably write on for my own, but don't know where I could get a dictionary of WM. Parsing .H files perspective drives me mad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a version of "Spy" installed as part of most windows mobile SDK's under the remote tools.  So if you have MSVC with either the builtin Windows Mobile SDK or you have installed a windows mobile SDK then you should be able to find it: (at least for vc2008 install)

\Program Files\CE Remote Tools\5.01\bin\ccspy.exe

Run it under windows and connect it to a windows mobile device.  It works similar to the standard spy++ but more limited.